# Why "use properties to hide functional implementation" when designing for inheritance?

Tags: python, oop

The following is a [paragraph in PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id40). I don't understand "In that case, use properties to hide functional implementation behind simple data attribute access syntax." and the Note 3:

> For simple public data attributes, it is best to expose just the attribute name, without complicated accessor/mutator methods. Keep in mind that Python provides an easy path to future enhancement, should you find that a simple data attribute needs to grow functional behavior. In that case, use properties to hide functional implementation behind simple data attribute access syntax.
>
> Note 1: Properties only work on new-style classes.
>
> Note 2: Try to keep the functional behavior side-effect free, although side-effects such as caching are generally fine.
>
> Note 3: Avoid using properties for computationally expensive operations; the attribute notation makes the caller believe that access is (relatively) cheap.

Comment: Do you know what properties are?  If not, start by reading [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) and learn more about them.

Comment: It does seem a contradiction; if the attribute grows functional behaviour, who's to know whether it will become expensive? But hiding the complexity communicates cheapness to the user, whatever is going on under the covers.

Comment: Please narrow down what you don't understand / need to know. Otherwise, this question may be closed as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @PeterWood: Fair enough, but that's the point of Note 3 (IMHO): if you suspect that the computation may become expensive in future versions then your interface should use explicit setter & getter methods. Otherwise, keep the interface simple by using properties so that simple attribute access can be used. But then I guess the question is: what's the cut-off point in computational expense? My gut feeling is that if your setter / getter can be done in O(1) it's probably ok to "hide" it as a property, unless it's (say) an order of magnitude slower than a true attribute access.

Comment: @pm2ring it isn't really a matter of foresight - Guido has previously argued (to no particular objection) that a significant change in complexity (for definitions of "significant") is likely already enough of a break in compatibility to deserve a changes interface.

Comment: @lvc: Oh, ok. Still, I prefer interfaces to be stable, when that's practical.

Comment: From [PEP20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): *Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules. Although practicality beats purity*

Answer (score 1):

The goal of hiding implementation is to keep an API constant.

If you have designed a class with a simple attribute and later you find out that a subclass needs a computation to return the proper value, you just replace the simple attribute by a computed attribute and the related API remains unchanged. A computed attribute is better known as a property.

Note 3 is a suggestion to keep in mind when designing a class, not when subclassing it.